# What kind of algorithms are used to break down data?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-algorithm

I have a table with a large amount of data and need to do lookups on each and break down each of the data.  Here's a simplified numeric example.  I have this table:

```
1 [1]
2 [1, 1]
4 [2, 2]
```

now I want to break down 4.  I look up and see 2+2=4. so then I look up 2 and see if breaks down into 1+1 so I know 2+1+1=4 and 1+1+1+1=4. For this problem, I should break it down(using the computed table) into 4 results(the 3 mentioned and 4 *1 =4).

I am not sure but is this a graph problem? or some other type?  I think I can solve this by just using a recursions that break this down, but I want to learn if there's an general accepted way and this process will deal with large amounts of data so I'll need to design it in a way that the breakdown can be distributed over multiple CPUs.

Any idea what type of problem this is or the logic to solve it?

Comment: i would just call this recursion...

Comment: Randy..I was thinking about that but wanted to know if there was a beter way. 
@EricJ. I wish..Passed up the chance to study computers in school(took a business major) 10 years ago.  I am self-learning right now on some personal problem. Right now I am reading up on programming as I come across them but eventually I might go back to school and study.

Comment: What does "break down" mean in general?  Your examples aren't representative of "large amounts of data".

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for the question. I used a small example with very small numbers to get the idea across.  I'm not sure the correct term is but I have a value and lookup what values refer to it..and so on until I get every possible value combination possible.  Also, I guess large data is relative, but I was saying that because as the datasets get larger, I wanted the most efficient way to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As close as I can understand your specific example, it could be recursion, it could be a graph problem, it could be several other things, or a combination.  Not every programming problem can be sorted into a single neat category, and there are generally at least a half-dozen different valid approaches to any problem.

In terms of dealing with large amounts of data specifically, there are many, many different strategies that may be employed, depending on how it needs to be accessed (sequentially? randomly by offset? randomly by key or some sort of search?), how frequently it will be updated, how much data there is in relationship to the sizes of the various levels of the storage hierarchy, etc.

And then there's multiple CPUs -- parallel processing -- where data synchronization becomes an important issue, in addition to the other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was sort of hoping someone would say 'its a  xyz type problem' then I could start learning how to implement that specific algo. Like I mentioned, app gets a number and then looks up the results in a large table of values and breaks them down.  There is a sort but its another process I worked on, so those types of proceses are abstracted from this app.  Also because the of the multi-cpu, I was trying to figure out how to break down the process as much as possible so it can be split across machines and then rejoined at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the super honest answer.  Its a bit frustrating when you want to solve a problem and suspect there's a solution out there but never learned all the types of algo's.  I think I'll take your logic and read a few books on different algo's and then try to transfer my problem to the algo's I know.  Thanks again, Daniel.

Comment: My advice would be to work out a few toy examples, trying different techniques, to get a "feel" for the problem.  Some just on paper, some with code.  Notice specifically where you tend to loop, scan, recur, et al.  Think about the number of such iterations you'd do in a "real" problem and, at the very least, avoid approaches that tend to do N-squared iterations and the like.  Think about how the data will be spread -- imagine it written on lots of pages of paper and trying to keep the stacks of paper straight, etc.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.  I am going to try to follow your method.  Right now I was just used to coding directly with no real plan(just test stuff) but since I figured out how to measure(big o) my algo's..I have realized how poor mine are.  Your advice will surely help me get better.  Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: In addition to looking at algorithm order, consider page touches.  Assume that a page is roughly 4K in size, and any time you reference something in an array that is more than that distance from the last reference to the array, it's a different page touch.  Ideal is an algorithm that "walks" through pages one at a time, doing multiple references on one before going to the next.  Worst is an algorithm that randomly accesses thousands of pages in no particular order to obtain a single result.  Cache touches are a little bit less critical but work on the same basis only with, say, 32 byte blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is really too vague - you present it not as a real scenario or problem to be solved, but as an algorithm -

> I look up and see 2+2=4. so then I look up 2 and see if breaks down into 1+1 so I know 2+1+1=4 and 1+1+1+1=4. For this problem, I should break it down(using the computed table) into 4 results(the 3 mentioned and 4 *1 =4).

You aren't asking how to do something - you're telling us what you want to do and asking the name of that activity.

From your question it's clear that you know what you need to do. Your process should be

- write the program to do whatever needs to be done
- if you get stuck at a particular point then research or ask a *specific* question
- and if it doesn't work or needs improvement then ask a *specific* question related to the problem area

Comment: I understand, Kirk. I think most problems I can solve but often my solutions are not effective.  I was trying to figure out if an existing solution exists and I could implement it. I figured, why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That's fair enough. Yet often times it's easier to carve up a simple wheel than try to attach a tractor wheel to your wagon.

Comment: I did follow your advice though, and created my own version of how I would approach the problem.  Its not the most efficient I'm sure but I'll keep getting better as I make more mistakes.  I think I'm going to spend this month reading more algo books to get a more broad understanding so I can ask more intelligent algo related questions.  Thanks for your answer and advice, Kirk.